# Blacklisting for Adblocker

Tags: firefox, ads

I am using [Adblock Plus](https://adblockplus.org/) on Firefox on Ubuntu.

I would like to only block some major pages like YouTube (maybe up to 4 websites). For all other sites, I would like to turn it off by default. Its a big struggle to turn off adblocker on every new site and refresh the page.

Any advice how to do blacklisting only those pages that annoy me most?

Comment: Web browsers extensions/add-ons are off-topic on [webapps.se]  unless the question is about using them to interact directly with a specific web application (ref [help/on-topic])

Answer (score -1):

I recommend Ublock Origin which is forked from Adblock extension and developed by the community. Ublock Origin allows configuring to enable or disable filters and you can import your filtered list easily.

[image]